# How can i set a simple string value returned from http.post to a variable in Angular5

Tags: angular, resteasy, angular5

I want to take a token from my Restful webservice with http.post. The webservice takes an username and password, if parameters match with any user in database it creates a token and return it as a string. I can send post and take the value as JSON but i want to take it as string. and i wanna use it as variable. And i want to have clear knowledge about http and rest service comunication if anyone can suggest a source it would be very nice to me. Thanks in advance...

i can take it with this but i wanna take it as a variable or a variable inside a class
Interface :

```
export interface Token {
    token: string
}
```

auth.service.ts :

```
login (username: string, password: string): Observable<Token[]> {
      this.params = '?username=' + username + '&password=' + password;
      return this.http.post<Token[]>(this.loginURL + this.params, null, httpOptions).do(data => console.log(data));
  }
```

login.component.ts :

```
this.authService.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(data => this.authService.token = data[0]);
```

**UPDATED AND WORKING**

I solved it with @SrAxi's help. The Final correct code;

my login.component.ts :

```
this.authService.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(
            (data: string) => this.authService.token.token = data,
            (error: any) => console.error(error.message, error.details),() => console.log(this.authService.token.token)
        );
```

My auth.service.ts :

```
 login(username: string, password: string): Observable<string> {
        this.params = '?username=' + username + '&password=' + password;
        return this.http.post(this.loginURL + this.params, null, httpOptions)
            .map((response: Token) => response.token) // we navigate in the repsonse directly and fish out the token and return it
            .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error));
    }
```

and my object class :

```
export class Token {
    private _token: string;


    get token(): string {
        return this._token;
    }

    set token(value: string) {
        this._token = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not mapping the response from your Http call.

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<string> {
    this.params = '?username=' + username + '&password=' + password;
    return this.http.post(this.loginURL + this.params, null, httpOptions)
      .map((response: any) => response.json().token) // we navigate in the repsonse directly and fish out the token and return it
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error));
  }
```

With this reworked function you'll be able to map the response and parse it as a JSON or to throw an error that your subscription will catch.

So you could call it like this:

```
this.authService.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(
      (data: any) => this.authService.token = data[0],
      (error: any) => console.error(error.message, error.details)
    );
```

Comment: can u write this function as return a string value to an string variable?

Comment: @KadirKalkan Edited the answer

Comment: ERROR in src/app/+auth/auth.service.ts(31,41): error TS2339: Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'. -- it returns this error in command prompt

Comment: Check the updated `.catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error));` Try it this way! ;)

Comment: still it returns this exception on compiling. the ide gives red underline error on ".json() " expression.

Comment: ok i did it thank you i will write the final and you can update your answer and i will correct yours.

Comment: Try this so you don't get the red underline: `(response: any) => response.json().token`. *(Updated also my answer with this change)* Anyway, I'm glad that it helped and now is working! ;)

Comment: thank you again i add a answer u can see it under of the page. :)

Comment: @KadirKalkan Hey friend, I know you're new to SO. If my answer helped to solve your issue you put it as the answer of the question. And this you did, Good job! Now, if you want to show how your code looks updated and working, you should edit your OP (Original Post). Maybe add a Title: **Update**, and then put your code there. Many answers are confusing for people reading. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In your auth-service do the following

```
login (username: string, password: string): Observable<Token> {
  this.params = '?username=' + username + '&password=' + password;
  return this.http.post(this.loginURL + this.params, null, httpOptions).map((res: Token) => res);
  }
```

Then in your login-component

```
    ...
    token: Token = null;
    this.authService.login(this.username, this.password)
   .subscribe(token => this.token = token);
    ...
```

Comment: how can i know when it return the token because when i try to console.log the token classes token property it returns exception when i try to write class it returns null